# DataLogic QuickScan - output of non-printable characters

Tags: barcode-scanner

I have a DataLogic QuickScan QBT2400 and I would like to enable non-printable ASCII characters.
In particular, I am scanning GS1 data matrices, which contain the  (group separator) character (ASCII 29), which is useful to determine when a variable-length field ended, but with the default settings, this character is not being output.
Thanks.

Comment: What hinders you to download and read the manuals? -> https://www.datalogic.com/eng/retail/hand-held-scanners/quickscan-i-qbt2400-pd-641.html

Comment: I've downloaded it, and I failed to find what I was looking for, but I can't read it all, it's definitely too long.

Comment: Please read https://superuser.com/conduct - think, hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours trying to find proper documentation and failing, I decided instead to analyze the scanner's behavior, and I found out that it outputs the `Oem6` key every time the group separator is encountered in the barcode/2d-code.
This does not solve the original question, however I was able to get the work done by making my program detect the Oem6 key and putting the group separator (ASCII 0x1D) in the string.